# Center logo + menu bar?

Tags: html, css

I am using this theme: https://themeforest.net/item/memento-multipurpose-funeral-services-html-template/23890802

Can somebody explain me where I start with centering the logo + the menubar?

```
<section class="page_toplogo ls s-pt-25 s-pb-20 s-py-md-30">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-md-end align-items-md-center">
                            <div class="mr-auto">
                                <div class="d-none d-md-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
                                    <a href="./" class="logo">
                                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The bit of HTML you've shown here seems to just be the logo, no sign of a menu.

Comment: Like Raxi said, we need more code to work with. This is only the logo

Comment: Looking at the template just now, the menu is technically already centered, but due to the presence of 6 menuitems + 1 searchbar + 2 buttonlinks it takes up almost all the available space (on xl desktop), so the difference between aligning left/center/right is almost not noticeable; of course, if you're using a lot less items in the menu, or have removed the searchbar/buttons, then it may become more noticable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to center the logo your can remove the mr-auto class from the html or this css

```
.page_toplogo .mr-auto {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

If you also want to remove those items to the right of the logo, either remove the html or hide them with `display: none` and  replace `justify-content-center` with `justify-content-start` to the logo wrapper.